# Что следует выбрать для разработки виртуального пианино - Java или Flash?

Tags: flash, java

Задача - разработать виртуальное пианино для обучения нотной грамоте. Скорость работы не имеет особого значения, да и мультиплеера никакого не планируется. Главное, чтобы всё было просто для пользователя. При этом, через некоторое время планируется сделать версию для Android, так что в этом отношении Java будет предпочтительней.
Просьба, аргументировать свой ответ.

Comment: Java и Java-под-Android — это очень разные вещи. Язык — не настолько определяющая вещь, вот используемые библиотеки важны. Библиотеки десктопной разновидности Java не очень умеют UI (да и звук вроде бы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash (AS3) так же позволяет делать мультиплатформенные (android/ios/win/mac) приложения, да и со звуком хорошо дружит.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JJU26rRruI

http://www.ehow.com/how_8297003_make-flash-piano-keyboard.html

http://ughzoid.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/dynamic-sound-generator-in-as3-basic-piano/

Comment: А есть ли сейчас бесплатные редакторы Flash, которые позволяют делать приложения для Android?

Comment: Не совсем Flash редактор, а полноценный IDE для ActionScript 3 проектов.

FlashDevelop - http://www.flashdevelop.org/

Для клавиш если что, нужно будет нарисовать картинки без Flash редактора.

Comment: Про Flashdevelop я слышал, только не понял, можно ли там делать интерфейс так же, как в том же Adobe Flash, а то с моим-то опытом писать код вручную будет, как бы так сказать, не комильфо.

Comment: Нет, визуально там строить графику нельзя.

Comment: Если Вы хотите учится писать код, а не делать анимацию для flash приложение ( на что и рассчитан adobe flash ), то начинать лучше с flashdevelop. Старт будет чуть медленнее, но эффективней.

Answer (score 0):

Бери Java или Javascript
- больше возможностей
- очень быстрая реализация - я видел уже готовые небольшие програмки с пианино
- совместимость везде 
Недостатки флеш:
- может тормозить
- может не везде поддерживаться

Answer (score 0):

Близкий к флэшу вариант: [язык Haxe](http://haxe.org/) и OpenFL (открытая реализация Flash API, не зависящая от флэш-плеера). Синтаксис Haxe очень похож на ActionScript 3.

#### Плюсы

- Haxe как язык куда мощнее AS3, JS и Java. Хотя на счёт Java 8 я уже не так уверен.
- Под Андроидом приложение будет собрано с лёгкой обёрткой на С++ и будет работать довольно быстро. Сборка, в виденных мной местах, делается одной командой.
- FlashDevelop под Windows удобен для разработки и поддерживает Haxe. При желании можно работать на Маке или в Линуксе в другой среде.
- На OpenFL много движков/фреймворков, некоторые из них это прямые порты с флэша, так что если раньше с ним работали, многое будет знакомо.
- Открытый код. Если вас это интересует.
- Свой менеджер библиотек и зависимостей, `haxelib`, почти любая библиотека ставится одной командой.

#### Минусы

- Документация только на английском и не идеальная, и обращаться с вопросами к сообществу наверняка придётся.
- Русскоязычное сообщество Haxe не слишком велико. Английское тоже не слишком, но оно довольно плотное и отзывчивое.

Comment: Вы не упомянули в плюсах или минусах мощь стандартной библиотеки. Для нового языка (каким, безусловно, является Haxe) стандартная библиотека, вероятно, не очень мощная?

Comment: @VladD haxe существует почти 10 лет, так что новизна под вопросом. Он не стар, да. [Стандартную библиотеку](http://api.haxe.org/) я считаю хорошей, но поскольку подключать сторонние с помощью `haxelib` очень легко, я этот вопрос не рассматривал. Впрочем, да, чтобы что-то подключить, нужно ещё об этом узнать.

Comment: Спасибо, на знал.